# How could I add button next to "edit image" button in "Attachment Details"

Tags: attachments, backbone, attachment-fields-to-edit

How could I add button next to "edit image" button in "Attachment Details"

This is the location I would like to add button, Do you have any recommend?

[image]

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't look like an easy task to achieve with just a hook, although I could be wrong. I can point you towards the files you can investigate if it helps? If you go to wp-includes/media-template.php, there is code that generates the "edit image" button there. In wp-includes/media.php, it calls the media-template.php file to be used. Hope it helps as a starting point at least! Also just a gentle reminder not to edit these files, but to use them to formulate your own solution. Good luck!

Comment: you mean I have to do some kind of monkey patching?. Do you have any specific recommend. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by monkey patching haha but I'm honestly not sure of the exact solution. I just know it doesn't appear it's as simple as using a hook to add a button, but I could be missing something - hence why I pointed you to those files. I also know the media library runs on Backbone so doing some research in that area may help as well. Good luck!

Comment: Perhaps if you describe what you intend the button to do, we could maybe help with alternative ways to do it?          Or you could look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/yoimages/.   It adds a 'edit crop formats' button - possibly with javascript

Comment: Thanks, I want to add a button there and execute some code onClick without hacking at the core.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you begin by having a look at a question asked more recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985336/wordpress-media-library-attachment-details).

The best option would be to create a custom plugin so that the WP core doesn't get affected. Editing core files is never a good idea, plus you would lose any changes when updating WP.